# UITextView acting strange

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

When I enter a table view containing comments, the uitext field remains where it should, but when I exit and reenter, the text field hops up and it acts as though the bottom of the screen doesn't exist.

Even weirder, when I dismiss the keyboard, the text field goes back to where it should.

Comment: Sounds to me that you have wrong constraints for auto layout.